# How to reduce app data usage?

Tags: android, http-post

I have an Android app that sends an HTTP POST every 5 minutes with GPS data. The size of POST itself (including header and body) is less than 1KB. The response is also less than 1KB. However, I'm noticing that my app is consuming 40KB with every POST. After experimenting and eliminating all other factors that could contribute to the data usage, I'm certain that the POST is the thing that's 
consuming the 40KB. Is it normal for an HTTP POST to consume this much data? Or is it something to do with the way the Android OS handles network calls that adds so much overhead? Below is the code I'm using to do the POST. I'm using the Apache HTTP library.

```
public String callWebMethod(
        Context poContext, 
        String psRestUrl,
        String psMethodNameWithGetParameters, 
        JSONObject psPostParameters,
        long pnTimeout) {

    String sHttpPostUrl = "";
    StringEntity paramEntity = null;
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = null;
    HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
    String sConvertedResponse = "";
    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();

    try {
        // Set entity
        paramEntity = new StringEntity(psPostParameters.toString());
        paramEntity.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));

        // Send POST
        sHttpPostUrl = psRestUrl + "/" + psMethodNameWithGetParameters;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, (int) pnTimeout);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, (int) pnTimeout);
        httpPost = new HttpPost(sHttpPostUrl);
        httpPost.setParams(httpParams);
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
        httpPost.setEntity(paramEntity);
        httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        // Get response
        if (httpResponse == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "No http response");
            return null;
        }

        sConvertedResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());

        return sConvertedResponse;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you leave the socket open? There is some data transferred in the negotiation, but 40kb sounds like a lot...

Comment: I can, but it doesn't seem to be the thing that's contributing all this extra overhead.

Comment: I would use Wireshark to sniff the traffic to see what it is.

Comment: Nevermind, I found it. I was doing an HttpURLConnection.connect() to check if I can access the internet before each POST. Apparently, that connect call uses a lot of data. Sorry for the misleading question.

Comment: ahh, thats what i suspected. if you leave the socket open it won't have to make this check.